# DateTime::createFromFormat not working (PHP 7.2)

Tags: php

Hy,

I have some issues creating a DateTime object with this:

```
DateTime::createFromFormat(DateTime::RFC3339_EXTENDED, '2018-07-30T20:03:25.000+02:00')
```

or with this:

```
DateTime::createFromFormat(DateTime::RFC3339_EXTENDED, '2018-07-30T20:03:25.000+02:00', $ev = new DateTimeZone('Europe/Vienna'))
```

This are the errors I get in both cases:

```
"errors" => array:2 [▼
20 => "The format separator does not match"
21 => "The timezone could not be found in the database"]
```

someone any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`DateTime::createFromFormat` unfortunately doesn't support all of PHP's date formatting characters, including the `v` for milliseconds. `RFC3339_EXTENDED` resolves to **Y-m-d\TH:i:s.vP**, which contains this character - the effect of this is that the constant can't be used to parse dates, only to display them.

A workaround would be to use a manual format string containing the `u` format character (for microseconds) instead, like this:

```
$d = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.uP', '2018-07-30T20:03:25.000+02:00');
echo $d->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
// 2018-07-30 20:03:25
```

Note: obviously this means the microsecond value will be 1000 times smaller than it should be - if this level of granularity is important then you'll need to multiply it by 1000 on the way back out of the object.

Edit: [Parsing *v* made it into PHP 7.3](https://3v4l.org/jLWRn)

Comment: Thank you for your help!